# Okta API or standard CURL/ajax problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl, okta

I'm looking to pull the current user's login name from the Okta API, but I'm usually just an HTML/CSS guy so I'm struggling. I'm currently stuck with this:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://harmelin.okta.com/api/v1/users/me",

    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(data.profile.login);
</script>
</body>
```

I've used parts of that code in the past with other APIs but had to go a little hack on it. I know that my problem is authorization as I'm getting a 403 error. The Okta documentation gives this as a request example:

```
curl -v -X GET \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: SSWS ${api_token}" \
"https://${org}.okta.com/api/v1/users/me"
```

How do I get the authorization in my script? Will that provide me with what I need for future development (data.profile.login)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **NOT** include the SSWS token in requests from the browser. Anyone who reads the source of your page could use it to make modifications to your org.

If you received a 403, it's because a user is not logged in or the cookie is not being sent.

If the user is not logged in, they should log in using [the okta-signin-widget](https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget), [okta-auth-js](https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js), or [your login page](https://harmelin.okta.com/).

In your case, the cookie is not being sent, because it's a CORS request. By default, jQuery doesn't send cookies on cross domain requests. You can fix this by sending `withCredentials` in your request.

After the user logs in, the following request should work:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://harmelin.okta.com/api/v1/users/me",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(err){
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

(code not tested)

```
headers: {
     "Authorization": "SSWS ${api_token}",
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     "Accept": "application/json"

},
```